# Can Kafka be configured to not retain at all?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am very much new to Kafka, and i am researching if Kafka can be used as a real time messaging broker rather than retaining and sending. In other words can it just do the basic pub/sub broker job without retaining at all.

Is it configurable in Kafka Server configurations?

Comment: I saw that you edited your question, so I assume you read my answer. I would like to know what your thoughts on it were? Or are you hoping for a different answer?

Comment: @morganw09dev , i wanted to give it some time for other inputs aswell. Now i have accepted it since it answers the question. I would like to know if you have worked with node.js kafka consumers and producers. so that i can ask the specifics.

Comment: I have not worked with node.js before, I've only done Java. But there could be some overlap, so I'll help if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to accomplish this. One of the key differences between Kafka and other messaging systems is that Kafka uses the underlying OS's to handle storage.

> Another unconventional choice that we made is to avoid explicitly 
>   caching messages in memory at the Kafka layer. Instead, we rely  on 
>   the  underlying file system page cache. [Whitepaper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/srikanth/netdb11/netdb11papers/netdb11-final12.pdf)

So Kafka automatically writes messages to disk, so it retains them by default. This is a conscious decision the designers of Kafka have made that they believe is worth the tradeoffs.

If you're asking this because you're worried writing to disk may be slower than keeping things in memory.

> We   have   found   that   both   the   production   and   the 
>   consumption  have  consistent  performance  linear  to  the  data  size, 
>   up to many terabytes of data. [Whitepaper](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/srikanth/netdb11/netdb11papers/netdb11-final12.pdf)

So the size of the data that you've retained doesn't impact how fast the system is.